# Shibboleth ignoring configuration settings

Tags: apache, ssl, centos, shibboleth

When testing shibd from command line (`/usr/sbin/shibd -t`) I'm seeing this warning:

> WARN Shibboleth.Application : empty/missing cookieProps setting, set
>   to "https" for SSL/TLS-only usage

My app is in fact HTTPS only, so I want to extend this to Shibboleth (I am a development environment and am not in production).

Previously,`/etc/shibboleth/shibboleth2.xml` config file contained this in the ApplicationDefaults section:

```
  <Sessions lifetime="28800" timeout="3600" checkAddress="false"
        handlerURL="/Shibboleth.sso" handlerSSL="true" 
        exportLocation="http://localhost/Shibboleth.sso/GetAssertion"
        exportACL="127.0.0.1"
        idpHistory="false" idpHistoryDays="7">
```

So, I added the following

`cookieProps="; path=/; secure; httpOnly"` after `HandlerSSL="true"`

same section:

```
  <Sessions lifetime="28800" timeout="3600" checkAddress="false"
        handlerURL="/Shibboleth.sso" handlerSSL="true" cookieProps="; path=/; secure; httpOnly"
        exportLocation="http://localhost/Shibboleth.sso/GetAssertion"
        exportACL="127.0.0.1"
        idpHistory="false" idpHistoryDays="7">
```

Now the error I'm seeing when issuing `shibd -t` is:

> WARN Shibboleth.Application : custom cookieProps setting should
>   include "; secure" for SSL/TLS-only usage

Why is shib ignoring the `secure` declaration?

Comment: Your code uses "sercure" not "secure"

Comment: Fixed that, restarted shibd & httpd.  Config settings still being ignored (same warns as above).

Answer (score 0):

Using:
    cookieProps="https"

did the trick for me.